# Simple way to escape curly braces?

Tags: handlebars.js

Is there a simple way to build a string "{value}" with Handlebars? Perhaps something analogous to:

```
Handlebars.compile("\{{{var}}\}")({var:"value"})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Handlebars support whitespace with the `~` character. The following should work

```
Handlebars.compile("{ {{~var~}} }")({var:"value"})
```

Comment: I've also discovered that for unescaped strings, you can use Handlebars.compile("{ {{~{var}~}} }")({var:"<p>value<p/>"})