# Handlebars - output a value inside curly braces

Tags: handlebars.js

My output needs to look somewhat like:

```
{foo} bar
```

The problem is the value `foo` comes from either a field or a helper. I could make the helper include the brackets `{foo}` but that doesn't seem a perfect solution. On the other hand if I try:

```
{{{foo_field}}} {{bar_field}}
```

That doesn't work as tripple braces also render the field in a slightly different manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution copied from [Simple way to escape curly braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943334/simple-way-to-escape-curly-braces)

```
{ {{~foo_field~}} } {{bar_field}}
```